# Import data from inter cluster hadoop with different versions using command line

Tags: hadoop, distcp

Can you tell me the exact command to import data from hdfs with two different haddop version one with hadoop 2.0.4 alpha and other 2.4.0 version? How can I use distcp command in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have different versions use hftp instead of using the actual hdfs command. You can see examples [on Cloudera website](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_7_2.html). Use the hftp on your source cluster and hdfs on your destination cluster address.